# How can we visualize $ax+by+d=0$ in 3D space parallel to z-axis?

Tags: geometry, 3d, plane-geometry

In a 3D space, it is a special case of $ax+by+cz=d,$ with $c=0$ and it represents a plane $ax+by=d$ which parallel to the z axis.

But my question is how can I visualise $ax+by=d$ parallel to z-axis in 3D? (Please depicts with 3D cube)

[image]

My approach: GBCD, FGED planes are parallel to z-axis.

Comment: $ax+by=d$ is the intersection of that plane with the $(x,y)$-plane, ans this equation does not depend on $z$. Is it clearer?

Comment: @Bernard GBCD, FGED planes are parallel to z-axis. Am I correct?

Comment: If $G=G1$ in your sketch, it is true for both.

Comment: @Bernard $G1$ means?

Comment: @Bernard only GBCD, FGED planes are parallel to z-axis? And no other planes aren't parallel to z-axis?

Comment: To answer your first question; your G looks like G1. For your second question: there are also ABCO and AFEO, since these planes contain the $z$-axis.

Comment: @Bernard how can you say GDEF etc plane represents ax+by=d, it represents like ax+by+cz+d=0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Let $\vec{N}$ be the normal vector perpendicular to z-axis i.e. the plane $GBDC. $
And the direction cosine of $\vec{N}$ is $(a, b, c)$ i.e. $(\cos \alpha, \cos \beta, \cos \gamma).$

The direction cosine of $\vec{OZ}$ is $(\cos 90°, \cos 90°, \cos 0°).$ i.e $(0,0,1).$

Now $\vec{N}$ and $\vec{OZ}$ perpendicular to each other, therefore $\vec{N}.\vec{OZ}=0\implies(a,b,c).(0,0,1)=0\implies c=0.$
Therefore $ax+by=d$ parallel to z-axis.

The planes $GBCD, GDEF, EOAF, AOBC$ are parallel z-axis which represents $ax+by=d.$

---

**Special notes to clear the basic concepts.**

We could draw 2 normals $\vec{N}$ of z-axis on the above plane $GBCD, GDEF$

On the plane GBDC, $\vec{N}{\perp}z-axis$, $\vec{N}{\parallel}x-axis$ and $\vec{N}{\perp}y-axis.$And in this case the direction cosine of $\vec{N}$ is $(1,0,0).$

On the plane $GDEF$, $\vec{N}{\perp}z-axis$, $\vec{N}{\parallel}y-axis$ and $\vec{N}{\perp}x-axis.$And in this case the direction cosine of $\vec{N}$ is $(0,1,0).$

**Conclusion:1** Normal vector $\vec{N}$ parallel to any coordinate axis $\implies$ perpendicular to remaining 2 coordinates axis.

Again plane $GBDC{\perp} x-axis\implies{\parallel} {\to} xz-axis$

Answer (score 0):

Here, maybe I can help you to clear this doubt.

So, here is what I want you to do, go to the following 3D- graphing calculator(geogebra).

https://www.geogebra.org/3d

Use your cursor and move the set of axes, such that you only see the $y$-axis and the $x$-axis(the $z$-axis should be pointing towards you, ie pointing outside the screen)

Now type the equation you stated with fixed numbers instead of variables(only change the coefficient of $z$, what do you notice?

As $c$ approaches $0$, what happens to the plane created, you do even see a plane anymore from your perspective or just a line? How does $c$ affect the plane? (Does it rotate or move it somehow?)

When $c = 0$, does it interact with the $z$-axis when you change the other coefficients?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your approach. Could please provide any image which is parallel to z axis?

Comment: See the equations where $c=0$? You can think about the $z$-axis as a part of those planes, which means that extending into the third dimension, from a 2D-line, just extends the 2D line in that same direction(ie: parallel to the $z$-axis)

Comment: I am still not unable to understand your images? Please depicts more clearly.

Comment: @Bezier First think about the basic 2D set of $x,y$ axes, then imagine yourself extending the third dimension out, what happens to any lines that are drawn? They also extend outwards in the same direction that you extended the third dimension(ie parallel to the third dimension)

Comment: In my image which planes are parallel to z-axis?

Comment: @Bezier, by extending out the third dimension ($z$-axis) in your set of axes, we see that planes, AFEO, GDBC, FEGD and ABCO are parallel to the $z$-axis

Comment: AFEO,ABCO cuts the Z-axis, how these parallel to z-axis?

Comment: Even though it cuts, it is still parallel, just when the constant $d=0$, unless in your domain $d \not= 0$.

Comment: why ABFG isn't parallel?

Comment: Think about two basic lines in 2D, they are parallel(have the same gradient) when they do not touch each other($y$-int is different) or they are the exact same line(ie same $y$-int and infinitely many solutions). 
ABFG only touches the $z$-axis once. Its lines AB and FG and parallel to the $x$-axis while its lines AF and GB are parallel to the $y$-axis but not $z$.

Comment: I understand all things. But one thing tell EFGD, BCDG etc are parallel to z-axis but z-coordinate exists. So how  they represent ax+by=d where z-coordinate is zero?

Comment: @Bezier their $z$ coordinate is not $0$. For specific $x$ and $y$ coordinates, it has infinitely many possible $z$ coordinates

Comment: ax+by=d means c=0 not z=0 am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: how can you say GDEF plane represents ax+by=d, it represents like ax+by+cz+d=0?

Comment: @Sood plane GDEF has an equation where $c=0$

Answer (score 0):

What @Shooting Stars is trying to explain through his images about how the plane is parallel to the z-axis, not necessarily count that it intersects it. Note that the z-axis is the vertical axis.

Consider the function's derivate, where the function is given by $f(x, y ,z) = 4x + 10y + 0z$, and its derivative with respect to the z-axis is $\frac{d(f(x))}{dz} = 0$, because the plane is not increasing or decreasing with respect to the z-axis. Alternatively, it can be said that it is travelling parallel to the z-axis. Also, it intersects the z-axis for infinite solutions because, note that there are also no translations applied to in the x or y direction. Being parallel to z-axis and intersecting the z-axis are not necessarily the same thing in 3D space. They can both occur or either one can occur. Basically, they can be mutually exclusive.

Secondly, $f(x, y ,z)$ intersects the z-axis on infinite solutions, also because $f(0, 0, a), a \in R$ will always result in an intersection on the z-axis. Consider, at the z-axis, the x, y coordinates are $0$.